What is the significance of the word choice of Numbers 18:1?
Numbers 18:1 seems to change a lot depending on the word choice of the translation that we read. Guilt vs iniquity vs responsibility:

So the Lord said to Aaron, “You, your sons, and your father’s household with you shall bear the guilt in connection with the sanctuary, and you and your sons with you shall bear the guilt in connection with your priesthood. (NASB)


So the Lord said to Aaron, “You and your sons and your father's house with you shall bear iniquity connected with the sanctuary, and you and your sons with you shall bear iniquity connected with your priesthood. (ESV)


The Lord said to Aaron, “You, your sons and your family are to bear the responsibility for offenses connected with the sanctuary, and you and your sons alone are to bear the responsibility for offenses connected with the priesthood. (NIV)

To me, responsibility seems very mild, like just something they're in charge of. But "bear the guilt/iniquity" seems much more like a punishment. What do we think of the word choice in these translations? And are the sons of Aaron being given a job to take care of, or literally taking on the guilt and making them actually guilty?

The Hebrew word used is avon, which can be translated as “iniquity,” “guilt,” or “punishment for iniquity” depending on the context.
In the context of Numbers 18:1, the term is often translated as “iniquity” or “guilt” to convey the idea that Aaron and his sons are to bear the responsibility for any errors or transgressions related to the sanctuary and their priestly duties. This includes both their own errors and those of the people.
Ellicott's Commentary says this:

Shall bear the iniquity of the sanctuary . . . —It must be remembered
that the iniquity of the sanctuary, and the iniquity of the
priesthood, extended not only to the defilement of the sanctuary by
the transgressions of priests and people (Leviticus 16:11; Leviticus
16:15-16), but also to its defilement by the imperfections connected
with the services of the priests and the offerings of the people
(Exodus 28:38).

The translation as “responsibility” in the NIV version emphasizes the duty and accountability of Aaron and his sons in their priestly roles. While it might seem milder, it does still carry the weight of responsibility for maintaining the sanctity of the sanctuary and the correctness of the priestly functions.
The Pulpit Commentary puts it this way:

The general sense of the phrase is, "to be responsible for the
iniquity," i.e., for anything which caused displeasure in the eyes of
God, "in connection with the sacred things and the service of them;"
hence it meant either to be responsible for such iniquity, as being
held accountable for it, and having to endure the penalty, or as being
permitted and enabled to take such accountability on oneself, and so
discharge it from others. This double sense is exactly reflected in
the Greek word αἴρειν, as applied to our Lord (John 1:29). The
priests, therefore (and the Kohathites, so far as they had anything to
do with the sanctuary), were responsible for all the unholiness
attaching or accruing to it, not only by reason of all offences
committed by themselves, but by reason of that imperfection which
clung to them at the best, and made them unworthy to handle the things
of God. In a further and deeper sense they might be said to be
vicariously responsible for all the iniquity of all Israel, so far as
the taint of it affected the very sanctuary (see on Exodus 28:38;
Leviticus 16:16).

So, while the translations use different words, they all convey the idea that Aaron and his sons have a serious responsibility. They are accountable for maintaining the sanctity of the sanctuary and the correctness of the priestly functions, and they bear the consequences for any failures in these areas.



References




Strong’s Hebrew: 5771. עָווֹן (avon) -- iniquity, guilt, punishment for iniquity. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5771.htm




The English word, "responsibility" carries much more weight than many often assume.  For example, if someone says that the criminal was never held responsible for his crimes, we mean that the criminal was let of without punishment.
In Num 18:1, the operative Hebrew word here is עָוֹן (avon) = "iniquity, guilt, punishment for iniquity".  One might also say that because the word נָשָׂא (nasa) = "to lift, carry, take, bear", it is reasonable that one could translate this as meaning:

"to bear the consequences of"
"to bear responsibility for"
"to bear the punishment for"
"to bear the guilt of"
etc.

The Pulpit commentary says this:

Thou and thy sons and thy father's house with thee shall bear the iniquity of the sanctuary. Aaron's father's house, according to the
analogy of Numbers 17:2, 3, 6, was the sub-tribe of the Kohathites,
and these had charge (to the exclusion of the other Levites) of the
sanctuary, or rather sacred things (הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, as in Numbers 10:21.
Septuagint, τῶν ἁγίων). See on Numbers 4:15. This mention of the
Kohathites in connection with the sanctuary is an incidental proof
that these instructions were given in view of the wanderings in the
wilderness, for after the settlement in Canaan no Levites (as such)
came into contact with the sacred furniture. It is not easy to define
exactly the meaning of "shall bear the iniquity (תִּשְׂאוּ אֶת־עַון)
of the sanctuary." The general sense of the phrase is, "to be
responsible for the iniquity," i.e., for anything which caused
displeasure in the eyes of God, "in connection with the sacred things
and the service of them;" hence it meant either to be responsible for
such iniquity, as being held accountable for it, and having to endure
the penalty, or as being permitted and enabled to take such
accountability on oneself, and so discharge it from others.


+1. Seems like we had the similar idea to quote the Pulpit Commentary. Your example of responsibility is a good one to portray the weight it carries.
